# How to include (import) markdown file content in Docusaurus V2?

Tags: docusaurus

Is there any way to include markdown file content into another markdown file in Docusaurus V2? I'm trying to organize my docs folder structure.

When we create a markdown file, e.g. in docs, Docusaurus automatically sets up the file path in some other project files. I'd like to know how do I make it works with folders into docs folder?

```
.
├── docc
│   ├── chapter1
│   │   ├── index.md
│   │   ├── session1.md
│   │   └── session2.md
│   └── chapter2
│       ├── index.md
│       ├── session1.md
│       └── session2.md
├── doc1.md
├── doc2.md
└── doc3.md
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done within .mdx files like this, check the docs [here](https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/#mdx-provider):

```
import License from './license.md' // Assumes an integration is used to compile MDX -> JS.
import Contributing from './docs/contributing.mdx'

# Hello world

<License components={props.components} />

---

<Contributing components={props.components} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Docusaurus' documentation doesn't shout this out loud, but it's possible to [do this without any plugins](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react#importing-markdown).

In your case, the markdown files that contain common content (`session1.md` and `session2.md`) would have to be renamed with an initial `_` character that would exclude them from being doc pages. Your folder structure could then look like:

```
.
├── docc
│   ├── chapter1
│   │   └── index.mdx
│   └── chapter2
│       └── index.mdx
├── common
│   ├── _session1.md
│   └── _session2.md
├── doc1.md
├── doc2.md
└── doc3.md
```

Notice that `index.md` is now `index.mdx`, which indicates it contains markdown extension syntax (similar to js and jsx).

Inside your index.mdx, you'd have something like this:

```
import Session from "../../common/_session1.md"


...


<Session1 />
```

Comment: This example seems incomplete to me. What is `Session` in `import Session`? How is that defined? What is `Session1`? Also I don't know why the `mdx` extension is necessary since Docusaurus treats both `md` and `mdx` extensions as MDX [by default](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features#mdx-vs-commonmark)

Comment: `Session` is just an alias for whatever is the default export from `_session1.md` (it's standard ES6 syntax). I think the treatment of `md` and `mdx` files might have changed in v3

Comment: The treatment of `md` and `mdx` is the same in v2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question fully, but you can nest content as deeply as you wish i think. You'll have to create your `sidebars.js` accordingly.

I have something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  someSidebar: {
    'Manual': [
      'intro',
      'login',
      'admin',
      {
        'Services': [
          'services/service1',
          'services/service2',
          'services/service3',
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to import markdown content into another markdown file.

Answer (score -1):

Change extension of `.md` file to `.mdx` and install [zero-md](https://github.com/zerodevx/zero-md).

```sh
$ npm install --save zero-md
```

In the `.mdx` file after Frontmatter add `import ZeroMd from 'zero-md'` and put `<zero-md src='{address of markdown file which you want to render}'></zero-md>` where you want to render the markdown file.

Comment: @Jeff Pal does this work with you?

Comment: That approach doesn't work.